# Invalid syntax jinja2 template value

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

Why does **max_height** produce an invalid syntax error?

**main.py**

```
max_height = 70

template_values = {   
   'max_height': max_height    # syntax error
   ...
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>      
        {% for person in people %}
            {% if person.filter("height <", max_height %)
                <b>{{ person.first_name }}</b> 
                <b>{{ person.last_name }}</b>
                <b>{{ person.city }}</b> 
                <b>{{ person.birth_year }}</b> 
                <b>{{ person.height }}</b> 
                <hr></hr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 1
Here is class MainPage from **main.py**:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        people_query = Person.all()
        people = people_query.fetch(10)

        max_height = 70

        template_values = {
            'people': people
            'max_height': max_height
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
{% if person.filter("height <", max_height %)
```

Should look something like this:

```
{% if person.filter("height <", max_height) %}
```

Also, I would advise against using any sort of filtering logic like this in the template itself. Put that code into your application code and just use the template to render the HTML.

Comment: +1 Thank you Blender. I fixed the code. I'm still getting the same error on the line: 'max_height': max_height. Is it that template values do not allow me to pass variables like this?

Comment: The error is ... line 20 'max_height': max_height. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Anthony: Try putting a comma after `max_height`.